# No "src" - Folder after creating a new Gitlab-Project and cloning it to IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gitlab, src

I just downloaded IntelliJ Idea to create a Web-Application with Java for Uni. But after I installed the JDK 17 and tried to Clone a new Gitlab Project to IntelliJ, it doesn't have the usual src-Folder.

[It just looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnZQx.png)

Can you help me here?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Do you see sources in the OS file manager? Try to close the project (File | Close Project), and the IDE, open the project in OS file explorer, and delete all .iml files and the .idea directory. Then re-import the project into IntelliJ from [Existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I do not see the src-Folder in the File-Manager.. the Folder wasn't automatically generated. I've deleted everything and reopened it - the Project was fully empty until I saved the project again, then it created a new .idea-Folder but that's it. I think it could be a Setting-Problem, but since I haven't changed anything since I've downloaded it, it's kinda strange..

Comment: Try to clone the project via Git CLI outside of the IDE and import the project into IntelliJ. Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

intellij Has some views. You can just click on "project" and select "Project Files"

[image]

And there is your src:

[image]

Comment: thank you for answering! Unfortunately, inside the Project Files there's no difference.. just the "External Libraries" and "Scratches and Consoles" - Part is hiding. There's no src-Folder..

Comment: In the  directory of your project there is the src?

Comment: No, only the .idea and a .git-Folder. It's like it wasn't automatically generated.

Comment: and in the gitlab repo that you've cloned, the src exists?

Comment: No, it's empty. But I've been watching some Youtube-videos about it and in every Tutorial they just clone it to their IntelliJ Idea-IDE and they get a normal project overview with the src-folder.

Comment: No, if the gitlab project that i've cloned doesnt have an src folder you will never have an src folder unless you create it. You should first of all create the first bootstrap of your project.

If you're using some framework, there are allways a form start a new project.

Quakurs: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started
Spring: https://start.spring.io/

Then create your project and push it to your gitlab.